# Don't leave food

Tags: vocabulary

When I want to tell a boy that he should eat up what he is eating now and not leave anything at all, what words can I say to him? “*Don’t leave food*,” is this proper words? What I like to know is if this word, *leave*, can be used about food.

Comment: You took it, you eat it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You could say:

> Son, eat all of your food. Do not **leave** any (food) on your plate.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in another answer, "Don't leave food on your plate" is a common phrase.

Other options include

> Don't waste food.
>
> Clean your plate.
>
> Finish your dinner.